# ZVS Flyback - GaN / Si

Tags: flyback, zvs, gan

I am reading a [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ucc28781.pdf) of a ZVS flyback controller.

In it are written the following lines:

[image]

These lines explain that the controller is looking at the switching node of the primary MOSFET (drain) and depending on what semiconductor is used, the voltage at which the controller considers that the ZVS is accomplished is different.

I do not understand why in the case of a Si MOSFET or a GaN, the ZVS point is not the same? Why it is not possible to achieve full ZVS with a Si MOSFET?

Comment: I think it is because the part is intended to drive high-frequency converters and the detection window for ensuring ZVS in auto-tuning mode is of small-duration in this part. Therefore, the resonant part in DCM where the drain falls down towards ground must be very quick, implying small \$C_{oss}\$ that only GaNs can have. If I understood the data-sheet well : )

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Well I do not get it. Si Coss is bigger than GaN Coss at this voltage level. So the time for discharging the Coss of a Si Mosfet is longer, so for achieving full ZVS, we expect to have a lower voltage threshold than for the GaN. Nevertheless what you said is different, and if i correctly understand you, you mean that as the detection window is of small duration it is possible in the case of a Si Mosfet to have not enough time to achieve the ZVS

Comment: Correct, I would suspect this is the reason: the discharge of the \$C_{oss}\$ would take longer time for a MOSFET than with a GaN transistor and could potentially exceed the allocated time window.

Comment: Thank you for your help :D (I hope that you are not burning where you are with this hot summer)